# Problema al añadir los ficheros javascript generados por tsc

Tags: javascript, typescript

primero agradecer a todos por visualizar la pregunta e intentar resolver mi duda.

Estoy desarrollando un fichero en typescript en el que realice la función de cargar un mapa desde un html. El cual cargará el fichero javascript compilado por typescript y que recibirá dos parámetros: "el id del mapa" y "el target del div donde se mostrará".

Primero lo realicé en Javascript, pero mi idea es hacerlo en typescript para importar las librerías y mapas de fondo por defecto para que los usuarios no vean cómo se ejecuta, sino que únicamente cargue el fichero js y desde el html llame a una función y cargue todo.

Lo que he hecho ha sido crear un fichero index.js donde hago las importaciones e implemento el código. Después, desde la consola escribo: `tsc` y me genera en la carpeta dist el fichero index.js y una carpeta con los mapas de fondo.

Eso lo llevo a una carpeta donde esta el html y añado la ruta al fichero index.js

Pero abro el navegador y me muestra los siguientes errores:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at index.js:5
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMap' of undefined at index.html:19

Mi fichero index.ts es el siguiente:

```
import { no_base_map } from './maps/no_base_map';
import { fulldark_map } from './maps/fulldark_map';
import { hibrid_map } from './maps/hibrid_map';
import { icgc_map } from './maps/icgc_map';
import { night_map } from './maps/night_map';
import { osm_map } from './maps/osm_map';
import { positron_map } from './maps/positron_map';
import { satellite_hibrid } from './maps/satellite_hibrid';

import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

var axisMap = {

    addMap: function(id:String, target:String) {
        sendRequest(id)
        .then( (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            // Create Map
            return createMap(data, target);
        })
        .then( (info) => {
            // Add Controls
            addControls(info.map);
            return info;
        })
        .then( (info) => {
            // Add Layers
            addLayers(info.map, info.layers);
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
    }
};

function sendRequest(id:String) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/map/' + id;
        console.log('url: ', url);
        fetch(url)
        .then( (res) => res.json())
        .then( (data) => {
            console.log('data server: ', data);
            if (data.ok) {
                resolve(data.map);
            } else {
                reject(data.error);
            }
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });   
};

function createMap(info:any, target:String) {
    var base = String(info.base); // info.base = 'nobase'
    var lat = Number(info.lat);
    var lng = Number(info.lng);
    var zoom = Number(info.zoom);
    var layers = info.wmslayers;

    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'my_access_token';

    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: String(target),  // container id
        style: String(getBaseMap(base)), // stylesheet location
        center: [lng, lat], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: zoom // starting zoom
    });

    return { map: map, layers: layers };
};

function addControls(map:any) {
    navigationControl(map);
    addScaleControl(map);
    addLocationControl(map);
};

function navigationControl(map:any) {
    var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
    map.addControl(nav, 'top-right');
};

function addScaleControl(map:any) {
    var scale = new mapboxgl.ScaleControl({
        maxWidth: 80,
        unit: 'metric'
    });
    map.addControl(scale);
};

function addLocationControl(map:any) {
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
        positionOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 300
        },
        trackUserLocation: true
    }));
};

function addLayers(map:any, layers:any) {
    if (layers.length > 0) {
        layers.reverse().forEach( (layer:any) => {

            map.on('load', function() {
                map.addLayer({
                'id': String(layer.keyName), 'type': 'raster',
                'source': { 'type': 'raster', 'tiles': [ createUrl(layer) ], 'tileSize': 256 }
                });
            });

        });
    }
};

function createUrl(layer:any) {
    var fullUrl;
    if (!layer.hasFilter) {
        fullUrl = `${layer.url}bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=${layer.format}&styles=${layer.styles}&transparent=true&service=WMS&version=${layer.version}&request=GetMap&${(layer.version.localeCompare('1.3.0') === 0) ? 'crs' : 'srs' }=EPSG:3857&width=256&height=256&layers=${layer.layers}&map=${layer.aditionals}`;
    } else {
        fullUrl = `${layer.url}bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=${layer.format}&styles=${layer.styles}&transparent=true&service=WMS&version=${layer.version}&request=GetMap&${(layer.version.localeCompare('1.3.0') === 0) ? 'crs' : 'srs' }=EPSG:3857&width=256&height=256&layers=${layer.layers}&map=${layer.aditionals}&CQL_FILTER=${layer.code}='${layer.filter}'`;
    }
    return fullUrl;
};

function getBaseMap(name:String) {

    switch(name) {
        case 'openstreetmaps': return osm_map;
        case 'icgc': return icgc_map;
        case 'positron': return positron_map;
        case 'fulldark': return fulldark_map;
        case 'night': return night_map;
        case 'hibrid': return hibrid_map;
        case 'nobase': return no_base_map;
        case 'hibrid': return satellite_hibrid;
        default:
            return no_base_map;
    }

};
```

Este es mi fichero HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Map Generator</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='js/index.js'></script>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:50%; height: 50%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

        axisMap.addMap("5b4f12233cfb101f4c2d0537", "map");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y despues de hacer `tsc` en la consola me genera esto, no pondré todo el código. Únicamente las primeras líneas para que veais porque me muestra dichos errores.

```
"use strict";
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const no_base_map_1 = require("./maps/no_base_map");
const fulldark_map_1 = require("./maps/fulldark_map");
const hibrid_map_1 = require("./maps/hibrid_map");
const icgc_map_1 = require("./maps/icgc_map");
const night_map_1 = require("./maps/night_map");
const osm_map_1 = require("./maps/osm_map");
const positron_map_1 = require("./maps/positron_map");
const satellite_hibrid_1 = require("./maps/satellite_hibrid");
const mapbox_gl_1 = __importDefault(require("mapbox-gl"));
var axisMap = {
    addMap: function (id, target) {
        sendRequest(id)
            .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            // Create Map
            return createMap(data, target);
        })
            .then((info) => {
            // Add Controls
            addControls(info.map);
            return info;
        })
            .then((info) => {
            // Add Layers
            addLayers(info.map, info.layers);
        })
            .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
    }
};
function sendRequest(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var url = 'http://localhost:8080/map/' + id;
        console.log('url: ', url);
        fetch(url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
            console.log('data server: ', data);
            if (data.ok) {
                resolve(data.map);
            }
            else {
                reject(data.error);
            }
        })
            .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
;
....
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Mi fichero tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

EDICIÓN: NUEVO PROPBLEMA

Ahora he creado una clase e importo por ejemplo un mapa

```
import { no_base_map } from './maps/no_base_map';

class AxisMap {

    constructor(id: string, target: string) {
        this.addMap(id, target);
    }

    addMap(id:string, target:string): void {
        this.sendRequest(id)
        .then( (data:any) => {
            // Create Map
            return this.createMap(data, target);
        })
        .then( (info:any) => {
            // Add Controls
            this.addControls(info.map);
            return info;
        })
        .then( (info:any) => {
            // Add Layers
            this.addLayers(info.map, info.layers);
        })
        .catch( (err:any) => {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
    }

    sendRequest(id:string) {
        return new Promise( (resolve:any, reject:any) => {
            var url = 'http://localhost:8080/map/' + id;
            fetch(url)
            .then( (res) => res.json())
            .then( (data) => {
                console.log('data server: ', data);
                if (data.ok) {
                    resolve(data.map);
                } else {
                    reject(data.error);
                }
            })
            .catch( (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }

    createMap(info:any, target:string) {
        var base = String(info.base); // info.base = 'nobase'
        var base = String('nobase'); // info.base = 'nobase'
        var lat = Number(info.lat);
        var lng = Number(info.lng);
        var zoom = Number(info.zoom);
        var layers = info.wmslayers;

        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'my_access_token';
        var style = this.getBaseMap(base);

        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: String(target),
            // style: String(this.getBaseMap(base)), // stylesheet location
            style: String(style),
            // style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
            center: [lng, lat],
            zoom: zoom // starting zoom
        });

        return { map: map, layers: layers };
    }

    addControls(map:any) {
        this.navigationControl(map);
        this.addScaleControl(map);
        this.addLocationControl(map); 
    }

    navigationControl(map:any) {
        var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
        map.addControl(nav, 'top-right');
    }

    addScaleControl(map:any) {
        var scale = new mapboxgl.ScaleControl({
            maxWidth: 80,
            unit: 'metric'
        });
        map.addControl(scale);
    }

    addLocationControl(map:any) {
        map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
            positionOptions: {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 300
            },
            trackUserLocation: true
        }));
    }

    addLayers(map:any, layers:any) {
        if (layers.length > 0) {
            layers.reverse().forEach( (layer:any) => {
                let fullUrl = this.createUrl(layer);
                map.on('load', function() {
                    map.addLayer({
                    'id': String(layer.keyName), 'type': 'raster',
                    'source': { 'type': 'raster', 'tiles': [ fullUrl ], 'tileSize': 256 }
                    });
                });

            });
        }
    }

    createUrl(layer:any) {
        var fullUrl;
        if (!layer.hasFilter) {
            fullUrl = `${layer.url}bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=${layer.format}&styles=${layer.styles}&transparent=true&service=WMS&version=${layer.version}&request=GetMap&${(layer.version.localeCompare('1.3.0') === 0) ? 'crs' : 'srs' }=EPSG:3857&width=256&height=256&layers=${layer.layers}&map=${layer.aditionals}`;
        } else {
            fullUrl = `${layer.url}bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}&format=${layer.format}&styles=${layer.styles}&transparent=true&service=WMS&version=${layer.version}&request=GetMap&${(layer.version.localeCompare('1.3.0') === 0) ? 'crs' : 'srs' }=EPSG:3857&width=256&height=256&layers=${layer.layers}&map=${layer.aditionals}&CQL_FILTER=${layer.code}='${layer.filter}'`;
        }
        return fullUrl;
    }


    getBaseMap(name:String) {


        switch(name) {
            case 'nobase': return no_base_map;
            default:
                return no_base_map;
        }

    }
}
```

Después de hacer `tsc` en la consola me genera el javascript peeeero, me muestra lo siguiente en el fichero index.js:

```
import { no_base_map } from './maps/no_base_map';
class AxisMap {
    constructor(id, target) {
        this.addMap(id, target);
    }
```

El nombre de la clase AxisMap se oscurece, como si después del import no interpretara más código.

Y me muestra los siguientes errores:
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at index.js 1
- Uncaught ReferenceError: AxisMap is not defined at (index):18

No lo entiendo :(

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir tu fichero tsconfig.json?

Comment: Si, claro.. ya lo tienes añadido :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro de si el segundo problema se resolverá al arreglar el primero, pero éste está causado por las líneas

```
"target": "es6",       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
"module": "commonjs",  /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
```

Si no usas CommonsJS (que es la librería que define la función `exports`) y estás usando los módulos estándar ES2015 (también conocidos como ES6, aunque el nombre oficial es el primero), si defines ambas líneas como `ES2015` (o simplemente eliminas la línea `"module": "commonjs",`), tu código debería funcionar.

Comment: mmmm cuando hago un import, como por ejemplo: import { no_base_map } from './maps/no_base_map'; estoy usando export en el fichero no_base_map.ts  export function no_base_map() {
  return { ... }; } por lo que si debería usar CommonsJS

Comment: No, `import`y `export`son palabras reservadas del lenguaje en ES2015, mientras que CommonsJS define una función llamada `exports` (y otra llamada `require`). CommonsJS era la solución de Node para poder usar varios archivos (módulos) al desarrollar con V8

Comment: ahhhhh... muchas gracias ya entiendo. import y export son de ES2015. pero tengo un problema... en el ts hago **import { no_base_map } from './maps/no_base_map';** y en el index.js pone lo mismo: **import { no_base_map } from './maps/no_base_map';** y me da los siguientes errores:
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {, se ve que no interpreta el import.
- Uncaught ReferenceError: AxisMap is not defined at (index):18, al poner el import en el ts, el nombre de la clase como que la oculta o no hay más código despues del import

Comment: ¿En qué navegador?

Comment: chrome.... https://github.com/jadelmag/MapFunctions

Comment: Vale, el problema no se resuelve de manera trivial, a ver si este fin de semana tengo tiempo y te pongo una respuesta más amplia... tengo que probar algunas cosas antes porque sólo uso Typescript con Angular y ahí está todo ya funcionando automáticamente con sus herramientas desde que creas el proyecto. En tu caso es algo más *manual*

Comment: Te pongo un ejemplo del uso de módulos una vez tienes el código Javascript: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/H4TxeSuegVY0r5Y1?preview

Comment: gracias, pero tu haces el import en el html, yo quiero hacerlo dentro de la clase AxisMap. el problema es que cuando ejecuto el comando **tsc** para que lo pase a javascript luego en el html no funciona. Quiero que el usuario cargue el fichero index.js y no sepa en el html todas los imports a los que hace referencia.

Comment: Yo tb solo uso Typescript con angular pero claro, quiero que ese fichero js se pueda importar desde cualquier html y le pase el nombre del div al que hace referencia... si lo hago con angular o react al hacer el build tb me genera un html y por ejemplo en react hace referencia al div con id root

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias [Pablo Lozano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22851/pablo-lozano) por tu ayuda :D
Al final, [indagando un poco](https://youtu.be/aWah7hLrSa8?t=7m30s) y viendo tu ejemplo... me he fijado en esto que no sabía: `type="module"`.

Para que el navegador reconozca la palabra clave `import` se tiene que definir en el script que es de tipo módulo.

Por lo que ahora abriendo el index.html en un servidor apache funciona y carga el mapa :D

Ahora, el problema que tengo es que yo quiero hacer que desde el index.html mediante una llamada a una función pasandole el nombre del mapa y el target se cargue. Y no desde el fichero index.js inicializando el objeto.

La idea sería la siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Map Generator</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script type="module" src='./js/index.js'></script>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.46.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        // LLamando a esta función cargue el mapa
        customMap.addMap("icgc", "map");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fichero index.js

```
import MapFunctions from './class/MapFunctions.js'

// Con el constructor funciona
// new MapFunctions().createMap("openstreetmaps", "map");

// Mi ejemplo de como debería funcionar
var customMap = {
    addMap: function name(base, target) {
        new MapFunctions().createMap(base, target);
    }
}
```

El problema es que me da el siguiente error:
ReferenceError: customMap is not defined

¿Cómo puedo hacer para llamarlo desde el script mediante una funcion, sin importar nada, Simplemente con customMap.addMap()?

https://github.com/jadelmag/MapFunctions